Как сделать умножение с данными, полученными от пользователя TELEBOT Python
Как сделать умножение с данными, полученными от пользователя TELEBOT Python.
Допустим идет сообщение от бота: введите число товара: вводится с клавы число, потом бот должен 18 умножить на мое число и выдать цену за всю покупку, больше вопрос у меня по тому, как все таки записать ввод моего числа в какую-либо переменную для дальнейшего использования!
import telebot;
from telebot import types
bot = telebot.TeleBot('*****************');
mm = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
button1 = types.KeyboardButton("Обратная связь")
button2 = types.KeyboardButton("Купить ключ")
mm.add(button1,button2)

otvet = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
button1s = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Windows 10", callback_data='Windows 10')
button2s = types.InlineKeyboardButton("office 2021", callback_data='Office 2021')
button3s = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Windows 11", callback_data='Windows 11')
button4s = types.InlineKeyboardButton("office 2016", callback_data='Office 2016')

otvet.add(button1s,button2s,button3s,button4s)

sm = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=5)
button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(" 1 шт", callback_data='1')
button2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(" 2 шт", callback_data='2')
button3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(" 3 шт", callback_data='3')
button4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(" 4 шт", callback_data='4')
button5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(" 5 шт", callback_data='5')
button6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(" 6 шт", callback_data='6')
button7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(" 7 шт", callback_data='7')
button8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(" 8 шт", callback_data='8')
button9 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(" 9 шт", callback_data='9')
button10 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("10 шт", callback_data='10')
sm.add(button1,button2,button3,button4,button5,button6,button7,button8,button9,button10)

oplat = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
buttonbalance = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Снять с баланса", callback_data="walet1")
oplat.add(buttonbalance)


@bot.message_handler(comands=['start'])
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text', 'document', 'audio'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text == "/start" or message.text == "Привет":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Чем могу помочь?", reply_markup=mm)
    elif message.text == "/help" or message.text == "Помощь":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Напиши боту Привет")
    if message.text == "Обратная связь":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Если с ботом что-то не так, то позвоните по этому номеру: 79*********")
    if message.text == "Купить ключ":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вот,что у меня есть в наличии", reply_markup=otvet)
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    try:
        if call.message:
            if call.data == "Windows 10":
                Windows10proprice = "599 руб."
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, f'Ключ indows 10 pro стоимость: {Windows10proprice}'" В наличии 7 шт.Введите количество", reply_markup=sm)
            if call.data == "Office 2021":
                Office2021price = "1099 руб."
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, f'Ключ Office 2021 стоимость: {Office2021price}'" В наличии 2 шт. Введите количество", reply_markup=sm)
            if call.data == "Windows 11":
                Windows11proprice = "699 руб."
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, f'Ключ windows 11 pro стоимость:{Windows11proprice}'" В наличии 5 шт. Введите количество",reply_markup=sm)
            if call.data == "Office 2016":
                Office2016price = "499 руб."
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, f'Ключ Office 2016 стоимость: {Office2016price}'" В наличии 8 шт. Введите количество", reply_markup=sm)
            if call.data == "1":
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Теперь выберите способ оплаты", reply_markup=oplat)
            if call.data == "2":
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Теперь выберите способ оплаты", reply_markup=oplat)
            if call.data == "3":
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Теперь выберите способ оплаты", reply_markup=oplat)
            if call.data == "4":
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Теперь выберите способ оплаты", reply_markup=oplat)
            if call.data == "5":
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Теперь выберите способ оплаты", reply_markup=oplat)
            if call.data == "6":
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Теперь выберите способ оплаты", reply_markup=oplat)
            if call.data == "7":
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Теперь выберите способ оплаты", reply_markup=oplat)
            if call.data == "8":
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Теперь выберите способ оплаты", reply_markup=oplat)
            if call.data == "9":
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Теперь выберите способ оплаты", reply_markup=oplat)
            if call.data == "10":
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Теперь выберите способ оплаты", reply_markup=oplat)

    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))

bot.polling(none_stop=True)


если ботом будете пользоваться только вы, то можете ловить данные из message.text, если ботом будут пользоваться 2 и более человек, то переменные не подходят, изучайте FSM, для этого, на мой взгляд, стоит отдать предпочтение в пользу библиотеки aiogram

У меня бот работает на pytelegrambotapi

Т.к. вы не предоставили свой код, то стоит только догадываться как у вас реализован выбор и показ товаров пользователю. Но, вы в своем вопросе спросили как перемножить цену товара с количеством, которое ввел пользователь, то:
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN")


products = {
    'огурцы': 50,
    'помидоры': 75,
    'лук': 60,
}


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Пришли мне название товара и количество через пробел:")


    @bot.message_handler()
def send_price(message):
    product = message.text.split(' ')[0].lower()  # Название товара
    count = int(message.text.split(' ')[1])  # Необходимое количество
    if product in products:
        price = products.get(product)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, str(price * count))  # Отправляем итоговую стоимость
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "У нас нет такого товара")


bot.polling() 


Я добавил свой код в вопросе

Я хочу чтобы после выбора способа оплаты умножалась цена в зависимости от его количество также, чтобы цена соответствовала товару количество которого выбрал пользователь

Также в дальнейшем планирую сделать каждому пользователю отдельный баланс

В начале кода создай переменную temp={}
И модифицировать ваш callback_query_handler
    if call.message:
        if call.data == "Windows 10":
            Windows10proprice = "599 руб."
            temp[call.message.chat.id] = {}
            temp[call.message.chat.id]["product"] = call.data
            temp[call.message.chat.id]["price"] = Windows10proprice
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, f'Ключ indows 10 pro стоимость: {Windows10proprice}'" В наличии 7 шт. Введите количество", reply_markup=sm)
        if call.data == "Office 2021":
            Office2021price = "1099 руб."
            temp[call.message.chat.id] = {}
            temp[call.message.chat.id]["product"] = call.data
            temp[call.message.chat.id]["price"] = Office2021price
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, f'Ключ Office 2021 стоимость: {Office2021price}'" В наличии 2 шт. Введите количество", reply_markup=sm)
        if call.data == "Windows 11":
            Windows11proprice = "699 руб."
            temp[call.message.chat.id] = {}
            temp[call.message.chat.id]["product"] = call.data
            temp[call.message.chat.id]["price"] = Windows11proprice
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, f'Ключ windows 11 pro стоимость:{Windows11proprice}'" В наличии 5 шт. Введите количество",reply_markup=sm)
        if call.data == "Office 2016":
            Office2016price = "499 руб."
            temp[call.message.chat.id] = {}
            temp[call.message.chat.id]["product"] = call.data
            temp[call.message.chat.id]["price"] = Office2016price
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, f'Ключ Office 2016 стоимость: {Office2016price}'" В наличии 8 шт. Введите количество", reply_markup=sm)
        if call.data in ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]:
            temp[call.message.chat.id]["quantity"] = int(call.data)
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, f"Цена за {temp[call.message.chat.id]["product"]}, в количестве {call.data} равна {temp[call.message.chat.id]["price"]*int(call.data)} Теперь выберите способ оплаты", reply_markup=oplat)

Так же я немного сократил ваш код

А что нужно модифицировать?

У меня все написано, вам просто нужно перенести мой код к вам в try, вместо того что уже есть

Почему-то при выборе количество товара ничего не получается

Есть какая-то ошибка, или просто ничего не происходит?

При нажатии кнопки количества ничего не происходит и выходит вот такая ошибка KeyError(6319780019)
KeyError(6319780019)
KeyError(6319780019)
KeyError(6319780019)
KeyError(6319780019)
KeyError(6319780019)
KeyError(6319780019)
KeyError(6319780019)
KeyError(6319780019)

А вы создали глобальную переменную temp={} в начале кода?
Еще можете попробовать заменить call.message.chat.id на str(call.message.chat.id)
